# Using $this when not in object contex call simple method in static method

Tags: php, class, oop, yii

there is my class Using $this when not in object context.

```
 <?php


class Adverts extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function getMainImage($id=0, $t=0){
         return $this->images($id, 'main-image', $t);
    }
   public static function mainPic($id, $t=0){
       $thumb = $t ? 'thumbs/':'';
       return self::urlDir($id).$this->getMainImage($id,$t);<---error line
   }

 .......
```

Why i can't call simple method in static method???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this` is reference to Adverts object. This object is created when you are creating new class by calling `new Adverts()`. Now since you are calling static method like this `Adverts::mainPic()` you are not creating new class object. So that means inside `mainPic()` there is no such thing as class object that is located inside `$this` that's why you can't use it.

You can access other static methods or variables that does not use `$this` in these ways:

```
self::methodName() // access current class or parent class method
parent::methodName() // access method in parent class
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually static method mean that it method related to Class not to certain instance of this class, so that why you getting this error, you cant non-static methods in static.

Answer (score 0):

First at all you should know the difference between $this and self:

> Use $this to refer to the current object. Use self to refer to the current class. In other words, use $this->member for non-static members, use self::$member for static members.

More information:
[When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this)

And you can't do that because you are trying to call a instance method from a static method, where you don't have the instance.

If you want to do that, you should change your method to static, and call it with `self`.

Or you could pass the instance as parameter and call it like `instance->method`.

More: [PHP static method vs instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976710/php-static-method-vs-instance-method)